# Could not login to google account via postman to preview firebase success response code

Tags: firebase, postman, google-oauth, google-authentication

I am hitting firebase DB by giving all required details (parameters, access token) and I got 200 OK response. The problem is when i click the next button in the postman to view response code, It's not responding. Is there any other way to view in postman instead of logging in to the google account.[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution for that?

Comment: No @BenyaminJafari I did not find. Instead I have put few extra logs and figured my problems in logcat itself.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add any code of your API, but you can send your google connection details via the API and it should works. read more here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database
or add some code

Answer (score 0):

Following some searching, I've realized that this feature (i.e. being enabled the JS in response preview) isn't available in the Postman application.

Here's its open [issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2646) on Github.